# Find Maximum M s.t Inequality Holds

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be any positive function with property:
$(1+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt)^2\leq f(x)\leq\frac{1}{2M^2}\,(0\leq x\leq M)$
What is maximum value for M?
Is M rational?

My approach so far
By first inequality get $\\1\leq f(x)$ and thus $(x+1)^2\leq f(x)\,\,(1)$.
By first inequality again the inequality (1) results that
$\\(1+\frac{(1+x)^3}{3})^2\leq f(x)\,\,(2)$.
We continue this to get more inequalities (3),(4),...

I think i have recursive formulation of functions that $\\g_{n+1}=(1+\int_{0}^{x}g_{n}(t)dt)^2$ and maximum of M comes from equation respect to M that
$\\Max_ng_n(M)=\frac{1}{2M^2}$
And M might be irrational
But Im not sure how to proceed with this.

Edit : I've got some clue that $Max_ng_n(M)=Lim_ng_n(M)$
and another approach can be made by giving the range for M.
By (1) $M\leq \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ and by (2)
$M\leq \frac{3\sqrt2}{8}$
Since $g_n$ are polynomials and $1\leq g_n$
Thus $Max_ng_n(0)=\frac{1}{2M^2}$ will suffice to get M.
But I don't still think M would be rational nor range for M to exist will reduce to {0}